# c# Form application, adding scrollbar to custom width

Tags: c#, forms, width, scrollbar

---

Hello, I was trying to do that last 24 hours but I couldn't ;-; I am yet nub c# so any help would be appreciated.

My problem is when I use for example:

Browser1.Width= 1680;

When application Width is smaller than the browser width it doesn't show a scroll bar, is it possible to let it do that?
Here's ex of how it look so I wonder if its possible to add scroll:
http://uupload.ir/files/hac_bandicam_2016-10-07_10-15-39-805.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(Browser1.Width, Browser1.Height);
```

A better solution would be to Set Browser1 dock to fill

Comment: Thank you so much this worked, its exactly what I was searching for.
however setting dock style couldn't do the scrolls....
I wanted to make custom height and width because the website I wanted it to browse isn't responsive...

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

In your form_load event, use

`Browser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`